# django-parsley: uncaught error

Tags: javascript, python, django, parsley.js

I am using python 2.7 & django 1.10.

I am also using [django-parsley](https://github.com/agiliq/Django-parsley) for the client side validation.

On each page I have the following error in the parsley.min.js file:

```
Uncaught Error: it is not available in the catalog
```

The error refers to the following code segment in the parsley.min.js file:

```
    setLocale: function(a) {
        if ("undefined" == typeof this.catalog[a])
            throw new Error(a + " is not available in the catalog");
        return this.locale = a,
        this
    },
```

Here is a screen shot of the issue:

[image]

**Does anyone have suggestions as to why I have this error?**

I have searched SO & Google, but have no real insight.

Comment: Either your browser isn't reporting a language & culture http://mybrowserinfo.com/detail.asp?bhcp=1 or it wasn't set server side. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

Answer (score 1):

Check your stack trace. Somehow, `setLocale` is being called with undefined or empty string as argument, instead of `'en'` or similar.